# R - test whether error term is homoescedastic and further related points

Tags: r, statistics, statistical-test

I normally program in VBA and studied business administration. But right now I have a task in R and am highly challenged on the following 3 points & would appreciate some help:

1. Test whether the error term is homoscedastic.
2. Test whether the explanatory variables are individually significant using standard errors that are robust against heteroskedasticity.
3. Use an appropriate test for the correct specification of the model.

How can I provide such a question in R?

Thank you guys very much!

Comment: maybe check this http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/39-regression-model-diagnostics/161-linear-regression-assumptions-and-diagnostics-in-r-essentials/ ?

Comment: it's really hard to answer your question without a context or a clear problem..